# What are the top reason to reconsider Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cms, features

Joomla has changed significantly in recent years. What are those recent changes which can help in making one reconsider Joomla for his projects?

Answer (score 4):

- **Joomla is Responsive**

  [image: enter preformatted text here]
- **One click installation via App Store** : Joomla call it 'Install from Web'
  [image]
- **Joomla is more secure**

  - 2 Factor authentication 
    [image]
  - Better encryption using Bcrypt : [Why Bcrypt is the best choice available](http://techchurian.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/144/)
    [image]
- **Multilingual right from the start of installation**
  [image]
- **Quick and Easy language overriding**
  [Video to learn how to do overriding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KiE-CtbZyY)
- **Content Versioning**
  [image]
- **Adoption of jQuery**: "Write Less, Do More"
  [image]
- **Joomla Framework** : Joomla has its own framework allowing the advanced users to create there own system independent of the protocols of the CMS. Using the framework enables you to define the structure and the logic of the applications.

Comment: You are answering your own ‘question’? It's not even clear from either pseudo-question or your answers whether you consider the listed attributes pros or cons. Please consider revising both. In future, please also consider not writing ‘questions’ merely for the purpose of providing your own ‘answer’. This isn't LinkedIn, it's supposed to be useful.

Comment: Its a wiki. I shared my answer, I can expect better answer from others too. This is recommended to build knowledge-base.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what framework you are planning on using with your Joomla site, as they differ so much.

I have used so many and have finally decided on the T3 responsive framework by [Joomlart](http://www.joomlart.com/). It's great and free, lots of help from the community and well worth a look.

Their free (and commercial) templates are very cross compatible and T3 is very customisable.

2.8% of the World’s Websites Use Joomla and aswell Joomla Has More Than 6000 Extensions.

Joomla's latest 3.0 release delivers out-of-the-box support for mobile users. While most open-source CMSs support MySQL, Joomla recently added support for PostgreSQL, as well as commercial offerings such as Microsoft SQL Server, Azure cloud services and Oracle. It also supports 68 different languages and offers a choice of 10,000 different extensions -- less than either Drupal or WordPress, but impressive nonetheless.

Joomla 3 introduced a full front end for end users, a new back end for website developers and administrators, and mobile support via an integrated Bootstrap framework.

Joomla is now available both as the Joomla CMS and as a general Web development platform called the Joomla Platform. The latter is a PHP framework that lets developers create standalone applications that can run on desktops, tablets, smartphones or in the cloud. While the Joomla Platform and Joomla CMS are separate projects, the Joomla CMS is an application that runs on top of the Joomla Platform.